# Why is C#.net removing my newline characters when I do a replace, and how can I stop it?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, replace

I have a textarea saving to a database that I'm using to send as the body of an email.

I allow tokens to be used as placeholders for information pertaining to that message.

If I don't touch the placeholders at all the email sends just fine with the line breaks exactly as they are in the textbox (the email is being sent in plain text).

However, when I start using the replace function, the new line characters start disappearing and all the lines get pushed together.

For example.

```
Body.Replace("%procedure%", CurrentOrder.Description);
```

Will replace the text %procedure%, but will also remove the newline at the end of the line.  Even if the newline isn't directly after the text being replaced.

Any ideas?

edit:

For now, I'm just replacing "\n" with "`<br />`" and sending the email as HTML.  I would rather keep it as plain text as I don't have control over the recipients at all.

**EDIT 2:**  It appears to be an issue with outlook itself, not the email.  I just viewed the exact same email in gmail, and the format was correct.

Comment: Are the newlines removed in the string in code or in the resultant email in outlook?

Comment: Have you tested this with different browsers? IIRC browsers differ in how they add line breaks in textareas, perhaps when .NET manipulates strings it 'fixes' what it thinks are 'broken' line breaks? .NET's understanding of a line break is accessible via Environment.NewLine. Just seen your edit - browser differences are more relevant if you're replacing \n.

Comment: @GregB I just ran a regular expression to see the match count, and it looks like the number stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook removes new lines unless the line ends with two spaces.

If you're testing the emails to an account that uses Outlook try adding two spaces before your new lines and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I just discovered that it was an outlook issue...thanks for your help.  I'll look into that.

Comment: This did it `Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "  ");`

Comment: After further investigation, you can just add a tab before the line break and outlook doesn't remove it.  This also keeps the formatting true rather than adding 2 extra spaces at the start of every newline.

Comment: You should replace with `"  " + Environment.NewLine` so the line ends with two spaces rather than the next line starting with two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If its for HTML I would first of all replace the new lines with BR tags:

```
String str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

either that, or instead of using a multiline textarea, use a JQuery or AJAX HTML Editor or something.

---

Maybe you could swap in a place holder (like above, and then swap it out?)